# Array key is lost upon multidimensional associaltive array sort

Tags: php

This is the array that I have :

```
Array
            (
                [02nd Apr-04th Apr] => Array
                    (
                        [facebook] => 0
                        [youtube] => 9
                        [timestamp] => 1491177600
                    )

                [03rd Mar-05th Mar] => Array
                    (
                        [facebook] => 0
                        [youtube] => 0
                        [timestamp] => 1488672000
                    )

)
```

I want to sort this by "timestamp" value. So the expected output is:

```
Array
            (
                [03rd Mar-05th Mar] => Array
                    (
                        [facebook] => 0
                        [youtube] => 0
                        [timestamp] => 1488672000
                    )
                [02nd Apr-04th Apr] => Array
                    (
                        [facebook] => 0
                        [youtube] => 9
                        [timestamp] => 1491177600
                    )

)
```

What I did :

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
              if ($a['timestamp'] == $b['timestamp']) {
                   return 0;
              }
              return ($a['timestamp'] < $b['timestamp']) ? -1 : 1;
})
```

When I did this, the sorting worked but the array keys were lost. This is the result I got :

```
Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [facebook] => 0
                        [youtube] => 0
                        [timestamp] => 1488672000
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [facebook] => 0
                        [youtube] => 9
                        [timestamp] => 1491177600
                    )

)
```

Comment: Here's something you can use http://php.net/uasort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `uasort` :

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
              if ($a['timestamp'] == $b['timestamp']) {
                   return 0;
              }
              return ($a['timestamp'] < $b['timestamp']) ? -1 : 1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

usort cannot keep the key, use uasort to replace it. And you can use <=> to simplify you compare function.

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
   return ($a['timestamp'] <=> $b['timestamp']);
})
```

Comment: its worth mentioning when you use php7 only syntax